# HTML5 helpers for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I may be off my rocker, but since **HTML5** came out, **does Microsoft have a namespace similar to**

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

for **HTML5** helpers in your MVC views?

I can't believe they don't have something out for this.... I'm using Visual Studio 13 Update 3.

**If they don't, can you simply apply HTML5 tags for the specific model you're using with the View?**

So, for example, if you just have an HTML5 input tag as text, can you say something like:

```
@using exampleModel

@exampleModel.Name
```

Comment: If you want a textbox for the `Name` property, then use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` or one of the overloads if you want to add additional html attributes. And you can inspect the source code for [System.Web.Mvc.Html](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
```

... the default editor templates in the latest versions of MVC will render input tags that correspond to the type you provide. For example, if the property is a number you'll get `<input type="number"...>`.

Comment: What if I want the input type to be of type="range"? Would all I need to do is set up the data annotation for that property in my model using the Range attribute and it will get rendered as an HTML5 input range tag?

Comment: @sagesky36: No. A lot of people want to specify that a number input needs to *have* a range, without actually forcing it to be represented as a slider control. You probably want to make a custom editor template for the slider, and then mark your property with a `[UiHint]` attribute to cause that custom editor template to be chosen.